# How to convert org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray to EnumSet?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, mybatis

In the TypeHandler of mybatis,I do it this way :

```
    @Override
    public EnumSet<E> getNullableResult(ResultSet resultSet, String columnName) throws SQLException {

        String[] enumNames = (String[]) resultSet.getArray(columnName).getArray();
        return EnumSet.copyOf(Arrays.stream(enumNames).map(name -> E.valueOf(type, name)).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    }
```

But something wrong here

`resultSet.getArray(columnName).getArray()`

The exception is

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.
```

But if I

`System.out.println( "resultSet.getArray(columnName):"+resultSet.getArray(columnName));`

The Console tells me

`resultSet.getArray(columnName):{Repository}`

How to convert org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray to EnumSet?

Comment: It does not seem to be related to `EnumSet`. Could you provide a small project on GitHub so that others can reproduce the exception? You can copy and modify this [project](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-64930633) if it's easier.

Comment: Sorry, I made a stupid mistake, the type of the field is wrong

Comment: No problem. Glad to know the issue has been resolved. :)